# gmsh, how to generate serendipity elements

Tags: python, mesh, gmsh

For Finite-Element simulations I need higher order meshes.
For sake of efficiency I want to use serendipity elements, i.e. elements without interior nodes.
The `setOrder()` function of *gmsh* was easy to find, it generates Lagrangian elements.

How can I set another element type, or somehow remove the interior nodes?
In the following example of a square in 2D the generated quadrilaterals of second order have 9 nodes each, I would like to have only 8 nodes per element.

Interestingly, *gmsh* seems to know these element types, as they are mentioned in the documentation of the file format `elm-type=10` and `elm-type=16`, respectively.

```
import numpy
import gmsh

gmsh.initialize()
gmsh.model.add("mini")

dim1=1
dim2=2

gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(1, 0, 0, 0.5, 2)
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(1, 1, 0, 0.5, 3)
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(0, 1, 0, 0.5, 4)

gmsh.model.geo.addLine(1, 2, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(2, 3, 2)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(3, 4, 3)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(4, 1, 4)

gmsh.model.geo.addCurveLoop([1, 2, 3, 4], 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addPlaneSurface([1], 1)
Square = gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(dim2, [1])
gmsh.model.setPhysicalName(dim2, Square, "Unit_Square")

gmsh.model.geo.mesh.setRecombine(dim2, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()
gmsh.model.mesh.generate(dim2)
gmsh.model.mesh.setOrder(2)   # generates Laplacian elements, but I want Serendipity

gmsh.write("mesh_order2.msh")
gmsh.finalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Christophe Geuzaine answered my question, the keyword is "incomplete elements"
https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/issues/1272
meaning for my example

```
...
gmsh.model.mesh.generate(dim2)
gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.SecondOrderIncomplete', 1)  # <-- that's it!
gmsh.model.mesh.setOrder(2) 
...
```